# in popsql when i try to run multiple times it says - table already exists

Tags: mysql, popsql

I have created a table named dbms
it runs once well but when I try to run again, it shows an error that dbms table already exists.
I don't understand what is the problem
can anyone help me, please?
thank you.

Comment: You can't create a table with same name twice in `MySQL`  and I guess for other dbms is the same. After all why would you need same table twice ?

Comment: Tables, once created, luckily are permanant. Otherwise all the data would disappear when you turned your back. Normally a `Create table` is preceeded by an `IF NOT EXISTS` to avoid this error, but a simpler way is to just run the create once

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't know but  `luckily` made me laugh. Couldn't agree more.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I cant write the problem appropriately.
I don't need the same table twice. 
I mean to say, i create a table with three col and it was okay after run 
CREATE TABLE info(
    id INT ,
    st_name VARCHAR(20),
    major VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
then I write code for insert value --Inserted into table_name values('something')
then I run and it shows table_name already inserted.

Comment: then I clear the cache and restart, then it ran well but after a few moments, it is showing the same problem.  @ErgestBasha

Comment: @AsifaAkter if you run a script for inserting data you should change `CREATE TABLE info` with `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS info`

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when working with databases, you only need to run the script once to create it. Otherwise it will not show until you place data into it.

Answer (score 0):

thank you, everyone.
but I found my mistake.
I was running the whole code again and again.
I just need to run a single line of code or a particular set of lines that need to be excecuted.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).